# SharePoint 2010 Modal box with multiple button redirects

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, modal-dialog

I am having errors with the redirect. It is taking me to the following page www.home.com/SITE1/undefined

I am implementing cookies and I think this might be the problem. The reason for the cookie is that I do not want the user to be prompted when they click back. The modal serves as a quick path to commonly used webpages. So I am going to include my complete code. I utilized 90% of this modal with the cookie function. I only wanted to modified it to include 3 more buttons.

Modal.aspx (page rendered inside the modal)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1">
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
    <style type="text/css">
        ul,ol {text-align: left;}
        li {list-style-type: circle; padding-top: 15px;}
        .subcontent {width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;}
        .domainName {color: Navy; font-weight: bold;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function closePage(redirectURL) {
        createCookie("Test", "ACCEPTED");
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, redirectURL);
    }

    function createCookie(name, value) {
        var expires = "";
       document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center;">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="Modal.aspx?IsDlg=1" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wPDwUKLTcxMDYyNDk4OA9kFgICBA9kFgICAQ8WAh4HVmlzaWJsZWdkZJ+th6rM5boAX+jz8z6RusiKXoWY" />
</div>

<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgK83aGICgKUxcvrDpIDY1zrMzRi62kcWf2pzau3Dch0" />
</div>
        <div id="ExSection">

            </div>
                <input type="submit" name="btn1" value="SITE 1" onclick="closePage('www.home.com/SITE1');" id="btn1" />
                <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="SITE 2" onclick="closePage('www.home.com/SITE2');" id="btn2" />
                <input type="submit" name="btn3" value="SITE 3" onclick="closePage('www.home.com/SITE3');" id="btn3" />
            </div>  
    </form>
```

The CEWP on the parent page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadDialog () {
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({
        title: "TEST MODAL BOX",
        url:    "www.home.com/Modal.aspx",
        width:  800,
        heigth: 600,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: dialogCallback

    });

}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
}

function LoadDialogWrapper() {
    var x = readCookie('Test');
        if (!x) {
    setTimeout("LoadDialog()", 1000);
        }
}
function dialogCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) {
    if(dialogResult== SP.UI.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        window.location.href = returnValue;
        }

}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("LoadDialogWrapper");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly in the modal dialog page create 3 buttons:

```
   <input type="submit" name="btn1" value="Site 1" onclick="closePage('Site1URL');" id="btn1" />
    <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="Site 2" onclick="closePage('Site2URL');" id="btn2" />
    <input type="submit" name="btn3" value="Site 3" onclick="closePage('Site3URL');" id="btn3" />
```

Then in the javascript method:

```
function closePage(redirectURL)
{
SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, redirectURL);
}
```

Now in the parent page:

```
function dialogCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) {
if(dialogResult== SP.UI.DialogResult.OK)
{
window.location.href = returnValue;
}
}
```

Comment: Could you help me with my revised code?

Comment: @Jeremy don't use window.frameElement.commitPopup(). Use only SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, redirectURL); to close the pop up.

Comment: It says SP is undefined this break occurs here at the `SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, redirectURL);`

Comment: @Jeremy make sure 'sp.ui.dialog.js' is loaded in the modal dialog page.

Comment: I was loading SP.js and SP.core.js I thought these will work I will give that a try thanks

Answer (score 0):

See this link then you can understand how to take multiple buttons.
http://www.tekritisoftware.com/sharepoint-custom-modal-pop-up-confirmation-dialog-box

For closing Dialogbox use: window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose();